# Implicit function-pointer conversions

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Empirically on tcc, gcc, and clang, a pointer to an
old-style function returning `RetTp` and a pointer to any prototyped
function returning `RetTp` are mutually implicitly convertible to each other:

```
//compiles without warnings
typedef void RetTp;
RetTp oldfn(){};
RetTp newfn(int X){};
RetTp (*oldfnp)() = newfn;
RetTp (*newfnp)(int X) = oldfn;
```

Is there anything in the C standard that guarantees such behavior or is it just an extension?

Comment: calling is the same. The only problem is how to properly pass the parameters. You probably will get the warning when you call them. BTW you have switched off warnings - you do not have return and have unused parameters

Comment: `RetTp oldfn(){};` -->> `RetTp oldfn(void){};`

Comment: C 2011 [N1570] 6.5.16.1 1 lists constraints for assignment expression, and the third constraint applies to function pointers, requiring that they be compatible. 6.7.6.3 15 specifies what makes function types compatible, but it is too convoluted for me to write up an answer now. It does allow a type with a parameter list to be compatible with a type without a parameter list, provided certain conditions are met.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that should be fine according to N1570. However, you should be aware that if you mix old-style declarations with function definitions containing a parameter type list, you should try to stick to `int` and `double`. Passing a 32-bit `int` to a function expecting a 64-bit `long` [can cause problems for example](https://repl.it/repls/JubilantLinedDecagon). Theoretically speaking, that's just UB at work, but practically speaking, it's the reason prototypes exist and why we should use them whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The implicitness of the conversion is guaranteed.

[6.5.16.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1) states that an assignment is valid if (among other things) *"...both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types..."* ("..., and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right").

[6.7.6.3p15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15) makes the function types compatible:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify
>   compatible return types.146) Moreover, the parameter type lists, if
>   both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use
>   of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types. If one type has a parameter type list and the other
>   type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a
>   function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the
>   parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of
>   each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
>   application of the default argument promotions. If one type has a
>   parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
>   definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
>   shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each
>   prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results
>   from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of
>   the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type
>   compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with
>   function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each
>   parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
>   unqualified version of its declared type.)

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but pay attention to the part that says "and the other type is specified by a function definition". Doesn't it rule that the types are *not* compatible?