# How can I make a function pointer that points to functions with different number of arguments?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am trying to implement a simple function pointer program, but I am getting this warning:

> Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type while assigning function address to function pointer

My program is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
int Add3Num(int a, int b, int c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int (*func)(int , ...);
  int a = 20, b = 10, c = 5, result;

  func = add;
  result = func(a, b);  // Warning over here
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 = %d\n", result);

  func = sub;
  result = func(a, b);  // Warning over here
  printf("Result of 20 - 10 = %d\n", result);

  func = Add3Num;
  result = func(a, b, c);  // Warning over here
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 + 5 = %d\n", result);

  return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b){
  return a+b;
}
int sub(int a, int b){
    return a-b;
}
int Add3Num(int a, int b, int c){
  return a+b+c;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the pointer as a pointer to a prototypeless function (a function taking an unspecified number of arguments):

```
  int (*func)();
```

Then your program should work, [without any need for casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847582/implicit-function-pointer-conversions) (as long as each call then continues to match the function being pointed at at the moment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
int Add3Num(int a, int b, int c);
int main(){
  int (*func)(); /*unspecified number of arguments*/
  int a = 20, b = 10, c = 5, result;

  /*Casts not needed for these function pointer assignments
    because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847582/implicit-function-pointer-conversions */
  func = add;
  result = func(a, b);
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 = %d\n", result);

  func = sub;
  result = func(a, b);
  printf("Result of 20 - 10 = %d\n", result);

  func = Add3Num;
  result = func(a, b, c);
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 + 5 = %d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
/*...*/
```

With prototyped functions, the match between function pointer types needs to be more or less exact (with some caveats like that top level qualifiers don't matter or that things can be spelled out differently), or else the standard leaves things undefined.

Alternatively, and perhaps preferably given that prototypeless functions and function pointer are an obsolescent feature, you can use strongly typed pointers (first `int (*)(int,int)` and then `int (*)(int,int,int)` ) and use casts to force things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
int Add3Num(int a, int b, int c);
int main(){
  int (*func)(int , int);
  int a = 20, b = 10, c = 5, result;

  func = add;
  result = func(a, b);
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 = %d\n", result);

  func = sub;
  result = func(a, b);
  printf("Result of 20 - 10 = %d\n", result);

  /*cast it so it can be stored in func*/
  func = (int (*)(int,int))Add3Num; 
  /*cast func back so the call is defined (and compiles)*/
  result = ((int (*)(int,int,int))func)(a, b, c); 
  printf("Result of 20 + 10 + 5 = %d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
/*...*/
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think casting function pointers invokes UB.

Comment: @alk You should be able to cast between any two function pointers freely as long as calls are made with a correct type.

Comment: @alk Found you the paragraph in the standard: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8

Comment: The paragraph states "*If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.*" Not sure which function type "*referenced type*" refers to.

Comment: Or perhaps I just do not understand what you want to express with "*... and cast to the correct type before each call.*"? Perhaps you like to add some code?

Comment: @alk Done. (I hope you at least plan to upvote for all this work you're making me do on this answer! :D)

Comment: Isn't here "*`result = ((int (*)(int,int,int))func)(a, b, c);`*" the "*referenced*" (aka pointed-to) type `(int (*)(int,int)`?

Comment: I'm not so sure `int (*func)();` is correct, given `int add(int a, int b);` then `func = add;`  I'm pretty sure calls such as `func( 1, 2, 3 )` would then result in default argument promotions, which `add()` won't be expecting.  `int add( int a, int b, int c )` probably "works", but `char addchar( char a, char b )` won't if arguments are passed on the stack.

Comment: @alk The referenced type there is (to my interpretation) the the type I've casted to, i.e., (`int (*)(int,int,int)`. The function being called is `int Add3num(int,int,int)`. The types are compatible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The default promotions will yield ints (no change in this case). `add` is expecting ints. There's no conflict there. It's all standard-approved (I'd have to look again, but I'm like 99.9% sure this is covered).

Comment: @AndrewHenle shouldn't it be fine because the pointer is being casted to the correct type before the call? Ignore my comment if the post was edited after your comment.

Comment: Related: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP37-C.+Call+functions+with+the+correct+number+and+type+of+arguments

Comment: "*The referenced type there is (to my interpretation) the the type I've casted to*" I always interpret this exactly the other way round. Namely: "The referenced type is the type of the function pointed to."

Comment: @alk But that doesn't make sense. It says .."used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type". If "the referenced type" were the same as the type of the called function, this compatibility comparison would be meaningless. It has to be the type after the conversion.

Comment: Thanks @PSkocik, thats what I was looking for.