# C: Passing a function without arguments to pthread_create

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

I'm curious if the following code has a well-defined behavior:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *f()
{
    printf("hey\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t th;
    if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, f, NULL) == 0) {
        pthread_join(th, NULL);
    }
}
```

`gcc` does not produce any warning if I compile it with `-Wall -Wextra` (see here: https://godbolt.org/z/fEvGesqad). However, I'm wondering why I can pass `f` as a parameter to `pthread_create`, because a function with the signature `void xxx(void *)` is expected.

Is it safe to do this, or will it lead to undefined behavior?

Thanks

Comment: `-Wstrict-prototypes`

Comment: It's the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847582/implicit-function-pointer-conversions. Note that your question isn't quite right -- pthread_create expects a function with signature `void* xxx(void*)` not `void xxx(void*)` as you say.

Comment: I believe C23 removes old-style function declarations/definitions. So this will be invalid pretty soon IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in both gcc and clang.

The C standard specifies that

> For two function types to be compatible [...] If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is
> specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall
> agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be
> compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument
> promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier [...]

In this case:

- one type has a parameter type list that specifies one parameter of type `void*`
- the other type is given by a function *definition* that has an empty identifier list for a parameter list, and so specifies zero parameters (as opposed to not providing information about the parameters)

It follows that the two types are incompatible.

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49884280/775806) quotes the same passage from the standard in essentially the same situation, and yet arrives to the opposite conclusion.